# Calculating digamma and trigamma functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, special-functions

What is the best method to calculate the value of digamma and trigamma functions? Wikipedia suggests using recurrence relations

$\psi_0(x+1) = \psi_0(x) + 1/x$, $\quad\psi_1(x+1) = \psi_1(x) - 1/x^2$

to make $x$ big enough, and then evaluating corresponding power series up to a certain term

$\psi_0(x) = \ln x - 1/2x - \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{B_{2n}}{2n \cdot x^{2n}}$

$\psi_1(x) = 1/x + 1/2x^2 + \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{B_{2n}}{x^{2n+1}}$

However, these series do not converge absolutely (moreover, $n$'th term tends to infinity, since $B_{2n}$ grows very fast), and I wasn't able to find any way to estimate residuals and relative errors.

Comment: Are in interested in evaluation for $x \in \mathbb{R}$, or do you need it over $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: These series are to be understood as asymptotic series, i.e. the difference between the actual value of the function, and the value of the truncated series goes to zero as $|x| \to \infty$, but the series itself need not converge.

Comment: Yes, $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Thank you, I didn't know about asymptotic series. So, let's say $x \geq 10$. How many terms do I need to get the relative error of 1e-8, for example?

Comment: I'd start by differentiating the Lanczos approximation for $\log\Gamma$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [reference](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0096300310010544). I hope it is helpful.

Comment: The link is dead. Do you still have this reference?